# Missing spark file from my system?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to run a program written in Scala that uses Apache Spark 2.0. However, I keep getting the following error:

`/opt/spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-class: line 86: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

**Edit:** Running the `java -version` command yields the following result:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)`

**Edit 2:** Took a peek into `/usr/java` and found that instead of `jdk1.8.0_40`, I have `jdk1.8.0_101`. Used `export JAVA_HOME` to reset it and now `env` displays `JAVA_HOME` as the correct path. It's still not working, though! Same error anyway. Do I need to run some kind of update command?

Comment: Do you have java installed?  Is this the correct location of java?

Comment: what is result of `java -version`

Comment: @FaigB please see my edit.

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` set correctly in the environment that is launching your spark app?